# udp local connection between 2 computers using qt

Tags: c++, qt, udp

I have a problem to connect 2 computers by using UDP protocol. As reference I've used broadcast server and broadcast receiver provided by qt (version 5.9). So what's the problem. When I want to check this 2 programs on one computer, they works correct, but when i use them on the different machines, all crashes. Datagrams wasn't received by receiver computer. What am i do wrong? Could anyone answer me.
sender code:

```
void Sender::broadcastDatagram()
{
    statusLabel->setText(tr("Now broadcasting datagram %1").arg(messageNo));
//! [1]
    QByteArray datagram = "Broadcast message " + QByteArray::number(messageNo);
    udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                             QHostAddress::Broadcast, 45454);
//! [1]
    ++messageNo;
}
```

`

and receiver

```
udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::Any,45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
```

sender ip is 127.0.0.1 ;
receiver ip is 10.0.0.10

Comment: That's not really how broadcast works, especially on the receiver side. Also, the senders *actual* address is not `127.0.0.1`, that's the (usual) address of the local loopback interface. If you bind to that address then all you will be able to send to and receive from is `127.0.0.1`, nothing else.

Comment: Oh, and to catch crashes you should use a *debugger*. Please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.